# Uploadify to work with ASP.Net and not MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, uploadify

I am trying to work with Uploadify plugin and works fine in uploading and displaying files.

As a known issue it doesn't supports sessions due to flash and the other fact is that we can work out by using MVC.

But I dosen't know anything about MVC and trying to work with normal Asp.Net application and I have seen many articles regarding Uploadify mentioned below:

http://geekswithblogs.net/apopovsky/archive/2009/05/06/working-around-flash-cookie-bug-in-asp.net-mvc.aspx

http://techblog.edwardting.com/2011/05/20/multiple-file-upload-in-mvc-using-uploadify/

Now I need to get it work with Asp.Net application.

I have created a Global aspx as said in the previous article and now Can anybody explain me in detail so that I need to create a session Id and save all the files in that Session Id and need to retrieve back with the Session Id in the OnComplete event.

So here is my Script code :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(
function () {
    $("#fileInput1").uploadify({
        'uploader': 'scripts/uploadify.swf',
        'cancelImg': 'images/cancel.png',
        'buttonText': 'Browse Files',
        'script': 'UploadVB.ashx',
        'folder': 'uploads',
        'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
        'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.gif;*.png',
        'queueSizeLimit': 9999,
        'simUploadLimit': 2,
        'sizeLimit': 4000000,
        'multi': true,
        'auto': true,
        'onComplete': function (event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
            $("#thumbnail").append(response)
        },

        'onError': function (event, ID, fileObj, errorObj) {
            alert(errorObj.type + ' Error: ' + errorObj.info);
        }


    });
}
);
</script>
```

This is my Handler Code:

```
 Dim savepath As String = ""
    Dim tempPath As String = ""
    tempPath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("FolderPath")
    savepath = context.Server.MapPath(tempPath)
    Dim filename As String = postedFile.FileName
    If Not Directory.Exists(savepath) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(savepath)
    End If
    If Not Directory.Exists(savepath + "\thumbs") Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(savepath + "\thumbs")
    End If


    postedFile.SaveAs((savepath & "\") + filename)
    Dim fullImage As System.Drawing.Image = New System.Drawing.Bitmap((savepath & "\") + filename)

    Dim newWidth As Integer = 100
    Dim newHeight As Integer = 80

    Dim temp As New Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight)
    Dim newImage As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(temp)
    newImage.DrawImage(fullImage, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight)
    temp.Save((savepath + "\thumbs" & "\") + "t_" + filename)

    context.Response.Write("<a href='" + (tempPath & "/") + filename + "'><img src='" + tempPath + "/thumbs" & "/" + "t_" + filename + "'/></a>")
    context.Response.StatusCode = 200
```